# How can save the information selected using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app using rails and when I do click on the icon of a product will show the product selected but is always replacing the product, I'm trying to keep the products selected.

Here is the controller:

```
def index
   @products= CustomerProduct.all
end 

def selected_product
   @selected_product = CustomerProduct.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is the index view: (Is showing all products and the div that will update)

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <p><%= product.product_code %>
    <%= product.product_name %>
    <%= product.product_price %>
    <%= link_to_remote image_tag("image.png"),:url=>{:controller=>"customer_product",:action=>"selected_product",:id=>product.id } %>
 </p>
<% end %>

<div id="list_products">
   ## Here is the div that will update after select a product.
</div>
```

Here is the ajax update that will replace the div:  "selected_product.rjs"

```
 page.replace_html("list_products", :partial=>"customer_product/partials/add_product")
```

Here is the partial view add_product that will show the information selected

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <p><%= product.product_code %>
    <%= product.product_name %>
    <%= product.product_price %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
```

Is working fine, but is always replacing the div list_products

[image]

Is there any ways to add a product selected everytime that I select a product?

[image]

Please somebody can help me?

I will really appreciate help.

Comment: Where's your try to send by AJAX here..?

Comment: `page.replace_html` seems to be working as intended

Comment: Yes is always replacing and is working....but i want to keep the product that i selected like the image example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `page.replace_html` you can do something like this

```
page.insert_html(:bottom, "list_products", :partial=>"customer_product/partials/add_product")
```

Comment: Damm... you are so smart... =) thanks for your answer master.

Comment: I have a last question how can I do to remove selected?